# Как проверить на Python пустой ли рабочий стол?

Tags: python, desktop

Нужно проверить, пустой ли рабочий стол на **Python**. Но проблема в том, что в папке, где расположены файлы с рабочего стола, есть **скрытый файл конфигурации desktop.ini** .

Comment: Укажите целевую ОС, пожалуйста

Comment: чем мешает этот файл?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
from os import listdir
from os.path import isfile, join
import os

# если количество файлов больше одного
if len(os.listdir('folder')) > 1:
    print('что-то есть')

# если в файлах есть desktop.ini
elif 'desktop.ini' in [f for f in listdir('folder') if isfile(join('folder', f))]:
    print('desktop.ini only')

# если вообще ничего нет
else:
    print('тютю')
```